# Limiting decimals of AUC to be printed with with ROC curve in pROC

Tags: r, roc, auc, proc-r-package

I have successfully created a plot with multiple ROC curves of different prediction models in the same plot and the numerical value of the AUC and CI is printed nicely on the side.

However it makes no sense for my project to have these printed with three decimals, rather I need the rounded version with two decimals and I have not been able to convince Rstudio to print it this way...

(to clearify, it says `AUC: 0.708 (0.661-0.754)` and I need it to be 0.71 (0.66-0.75)).

I tried:

```
print(ROC_rfhipfx60X1MOmospugholt, digits = max(3, getOption("digits") -3 ), call= TRUE)
```

which returns the call (seemingly succesfull at first):

```
Call:
roc.default(response = hipfx_pugely_and_holt_predictions_20200820$`1MO`,     predictor = hipfx_pugely_and_holt_predictions_20200820$`PUGELY RISK %`,     ci = TRUE, plot = TRUE, print.auc = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 4,     print.auc.y = 0.3, legacy.axes = TRUE, add = TRUE)

Data: hipfx_pugely_and_holt_predictions_20200820$`PUGELY RISK %` in 121 controls (hipfx_pugely_and_holt_predictions_20200820$`1MO` no) > 1050 cases (hipfx_pugely_and_holt_predictions_20200820$`1MO` yes).
Area under the curve: 0.7078
95% CI: 0.6615-0.7542 (DeLong)
>
```

And instead of creating a new plot it returns (same message gets printed again if I scroll through my plots and return to the one that is not working):

```
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file '/var/folders/22/nxnj3khn76q9hz0khppd11_40000gn/T/RtmpXrawRS/rs-graphics-7de8e907-4a56-4944-b16e-aeb4054ee835/2473fad9-4618-46c1-9014-fbcb61050b97.snapshot', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Graphics error: Plot rendering error
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
```

Comment: Do you want to print or plot the curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `digit` argument to `print` controls the number of significant digits. In this case it matches the number of decimals, as we are between 0 and 1. So you can use `digits = 2`, like so:

```
> library(pROC)
> data(aSAH)
> roc_curve <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$ndka)
Setting levels: control = Good, case = Poor
Setting direction: controls < cases
> print(roc_curve, digits = 2)

Call:
roc.default(response = aSAH$outcome, predictor = aSAH$ndka, ci = TRUE)

Data: aSAH$ndka in 72 controls (aSAH$outcome Good) < 41 cases (aSAH$outcome Poor).
Area under the curve: 0.61
95% CI: 0.5-0.72 (DeLong)
```

For plots I suggest you use the `plot` function separately. You should customize the `print.auc.pattern` argument, to plot the numbers with two decimals (this time it's not the number of significant digits):

```
plot(roc_curve, print.auc = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 4, print.auc.y = 0.3, legacy.axes = TRUE, print.auc.pattern = "%.2f (%.2f-%.2f)")
```

When you get plot errors from Rstudio, most often creating the plot fresh again will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That finally solved the problem, I did a new plot with the print.auc.pattern = "%.2f (%.2f-%.2f) inserted.

Comment: I actually tried that before but had "%#.2f" that I had from somewhere else and that didn't work. So the "2f" means 2 formated decimals, "%" is like "x" and the parenthesis is so that it even applies to the numbers in the in the parenthesis? Is that how I should read the code?  I am very grateful for your help, such a relief!

Comment: Happy to help. The format is exactly as described in the documentation of the sprintf function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sprintf

Comment: The parenthesis have no specific meaning here, they appear in the final output, it's just that you're formatting 3 numbers. So you could have fun and say `print.auc.pattern = "%.10f, and the confidence interval is %.4f-%.1f!!!"` to have 10, 4 and 1 decimal with some extra text and exclamation marks.